# How to Define custom types & verify correct value at compile time?

Tags: rust, types, newtype

I want to define new type in rust. Let's say for eg Date, which should follow dd/mm/yy format & value suppiled should be verified at compile time only. In gen, I want to define new types & add restriction to possible values.Just like i32 & other primitive types have restriction which is checked at compile time.

Comment: You can probably fairly easily do some basic checking, such that the `dd` part is in the range `1..=31`, but I'm not sure it's reasonable to do the full gamut of date parsing, including checking for leap years, at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most idiomatic way of doing this would be to write *run time* checks in a `const fn`, so that it can actually be called at *compile time*. Maybe something like that (I kept the checks very simple, but it could do more):

```rust
struct Date {
  day: u8,
  month: u8,
  year: u16,
}

impl Date {
  const fn new(day: u8, month: u8, year: u16) -> Self {
    assert!(day <= 31 && day >= 1);
    assert!(month <= 12 && month >= 1);
    Self { day, month, year }
  }
}

const TODAY: Date = Date::new(25, 06, 2022); // Compiles fine
const IN_A_WEEK: Date = Date::new(32, 06, 2022); // Compile time error

fn do_something() {
  Date::new(32, 06, 2022); // Run time error
}
```

See it [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=47b884fc982cf5e0d267f65e0d7e3a48).

Comment: I know this is just sample code, but the `drop()` invocation is redundant here, and it's likely to make others think they need to use it for some reason when they don't. Also `year` in `new()` should be `u16`.

Comment: @cdhowie good catch on the typo! As for the `drop`, I just assumed such a basic function wouldn't confuse much people, but since you seem to have a lot of experience on this forum (you answer / comment every Rust question I have seen so far), I'll trust you.

Comment: You usually only use `drop()` when you need to discard a value before the end of a block. A common example is closing a [`Sender`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html). In general, if a value doesn't implement `Drop` then there is no need to explicitly `drop()` as NLL will apply. (`Drop` disables NLL.)

Comment: @cdhowie I also though `drop` was useful when you are not using a non-ZST, otherwise the compiler would warn you, but I checked and it does not. I was confusing with OCaml's behavior and its `ignore`.

Comment: Ah, yeah in Rust that only happens with types/functions marked `#[must_use]`.